# Using Python (scipy or numpy) how do I calculate the 2.5th and 97.5th percentiles of the Student t distribution with 5 degrees of freedom

Tags: python, r, numpy, scipy

Using Python (scipy or numpy) how do I calculate  the 2.5th and 97.5th percentiles of the Student t distribution with 5 degrees of freedom

In R I can do it using

```
> qt(c(.025, .975), df=5)   # 5 degrees of freedom 

[1] -2.5706  2.5706
```

In Python I get this using 0.95 not 0.975

```
from scipy.stats import t

t.interval(0.95, 5, loc=0, scale=1)

(-2.5705818366147395, 2.5705818366147395)
```

Comment: The 97.5th percentile is that value below which 97.5% of all probability density of the Student t-distribution lies. Meanwhile, the limits of a 97.5% two-sided confidence interval have a probability of 2.5% of not capturing the parameter it is calculated for, which is 1.25% on either side of the interval. For a 95% two-sided confidence interval, that's 2.5% on either side, which is what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ppf` (percent point function) of `scipy.stats.t`

```
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> stats.t(df=5).ppf((0.025, 0.975))
array([-2.57058184,  2.57058184])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
scipy.stats.t.interval(alpha, df, loc=0, scale=1)
```

From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.t.html):

> Endpoints of the range that contains alpha percent of the distribution

Comment: I used it but got the answer with 0.95 not 0.975. What am I doing wrong

Comment: @AjayOhri The interval from 0.025 to 0.975 is 0.95 large